# dropdown knockoutjs with value from server

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I am working on a drop down menu within a TR .. I have true, false or none as the value that I receive from server and I want that to change the drop down option as in example below.

The first one is working but I want the second one to function as the first one

[Example is here:](http://jsfiddle.net/3xLgJ/) http://jsfiddle.net/3xLgJ/

**This is my HTML:**

```
       <div data-bind='text: incomingValue'></div>

       <select data-bind="value: incomingValue">
             <option value="true">Yes</option>
             <option value="false">No</option>
             <option value="none">Don't Know</option>
      </select>
```

How can I implment this as above as this is within a tr and to function as above

```
      <select  data-bind='options: yesno, value: incomingValue'/>
```

**Here is my knockout**

```
    var myModelView = function () {
    self = this;
    self.yesno = ko.observableArray(['Yes', 'No', 'Don\'t know']);
    self.incomingValue = ko.observable('none');
    };

    var moView = new myModelView();

    ko.applyBindings(moView);
```

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is probably to slightly reconstruct the view model to use objects instead of simple strings:

```
// Create a "class" that represents an option
var Option = function(id, caption) {
    this.id = id;
    this.caption = caption;
};
```

Now you populate the observable array with objects constructed from this function:

```
self.yesno = ko.observableArray([
    new Option('true', 'Yes'),
    new Option('false', 'No'),
    new Option('none', 'Don\'t know')
]);
```

You can use the "optionsText" binding to correctly bind these objects to the markup:

```
<select data-bind="options: yesno,
                   optionsText: 'caption',
                   value: selectedItem"></select>
```

If you receive a string "none" from the server, you need to find the object representing this option:

```
var incomingValue = 'none';

// Find the first object that is a match in the observable array "yesno"
var incomingItem = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.yesno(), function(item) {
    return item.id == incomingValue;
});

self.selectedItem = ko.observable(incomingItem);
```

When displaying the selection somewhere else you'll need to consider that the selection is represented by an object:

```
<div data-bind='text: selectedItem().caption'></div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3xLgJ/2/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `optionsText` and `optionsValue` bindings.  You'll need to make an observable array of values and text:

```
self.yesno = ko.observableArray([
    {value:"true",text:"Yes"},
    {value:"false",text:"No"},
    {value:"none",text:"Don't Know"}]);
```

then, you need to do something like this in your html:

```
<select data-bind="options: yesno2, optionsText: 'text',optionsValue: 'value', value: incomingValue"></select>
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3xLgJ/3/) for a working example

Comment: Great answer Tim, Just one more what if I have values from server like inVal here: http://jsfiddle.net/DQwwm/

Comment: You could update the value in `self.incomingValue()` every time you receive update data from the server.  Maybe something like `self.incomingValue(self.inValue[0].incomingValue.toString());`